# Nama Japa & the 12 Bhavas of astrology

Tags: belief, astrology, japa

Is the following theory true? :-

Astrology has 12 Bhavas viz: Lagna, Dvitiya, Tritiya ..to the Dwadasha Bhava.

If a person does 13 crores of Rama Nama Japa.

For each 1 crore, his 1 Bhava will get cleaned of Doshas.

Eg. If a person completes a Japa of 1 crore then the Lagna will get cleared of its defects.

For the next 1 crores, all negative effects of the 2nd Bhava will be destroyed and so on.

12 places in Horoscope are as [here](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https://astrolibrary.org/images/houses-wheel.jpg&imgrefurl=https://astrolibrary.org/houses/&h=300&w=301&tbnid=6Q9PGht_fzfDXM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=160&usg=__QJJc6XGQXrONVJ_Ck7i9Srzl2aM=&vet=1&docid=XMjli8wjjXL5EM&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjDmvL9qIrTAhUEMGMKHWDDApAQ9QEIHTAA#h=300&imgrc=6Q9PGht_fzfDXM:&tbnh=160&tbnw=160&vet=1&w=301)

Comment: what are those 12 places? Do you have any online link mentioning them?

Comment: @TheDestroyer Updated in question

Comment: no its not true ... for vaishnavas they say 10 avatars .. for shakta they say 10 mahavidya .. but any mantra is chanted strongly can help .. not only rama or any specific

Comment: Rama nama japa cleanses all sins and doshas. I am not aware of the specifics related to astrology.

Answer (score 3):

You can probably find similar references/claims in other sastras, with naam japa destroying sinful reactions or cleaning karma and so on. See some [here](https://nitaaiveda.com/Compiled_and_Imp_Scriptures/Prema_Vivarta/20._The_Glories_of_the_Holy_Name.htm) and [here](http://www.harekrishnajapa.com/2016/07/24-even-improper-chanting-of-the-holy-name-yields-beneficial-results/). You can find them in other Vedic literature as well.

What's also considered important to understand though, a caveat if you will, is that the effect may not be immediate, depending on how the japa was performed, with what intention etc.

Comment: is this answer related to astrology ?

Comment: You have not answered the question.

Comment: To be honest, I wanted to add a comment back then but did not have enough rep. I can try to move it to a comment (don't know how to yet though) if that seems a better place. Let me know. Also, the question seems to have changed quite a bit since I answered, and become a lot more specific (and technical), and I have absolutely zero idea about the astrological aspect of it. I guess I had just meant to say that I wouldn't be surprised if the said theory was true, but I also wouldn't take it literally or at face value.